# How to filter data in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I am working on react native project.

In that, I am getting multiple data from api like following.

```
{
    Value: "895"
    Return: "2"
    Return1: "0.20"
    Return3: "0.40"
    Return5: "0.60"
    Return10: "0.50"
    StartDate: "2019-06-13"
}, {
    Value: "900"
    Return: "4"
    Return1: "0.10"
    Return3: "0.40"
    Return5: "0.70"
    Return10: "0.90"
    StartDate: "2019-06-14"
},
```

But, I am trying to take all **Return** data to some return array which I need to show each index of data into flatlist.
But, Here I got confuse how to take it into another array because Return key has 1,3,5, etc at the ending of the key in each index.

```
const ValuesData = [];

if (ReturnsData) {
  ReturnsData.map((item, index) => {
    ValuesData.push({
     `${ReturnsData[index].Return`${index}`}`,
    });
  });
}
```

Can anyone suggest me how to take Return(1,3,5,10) data into array?

Comment: Can you create a runnable snippet? See how to create an [mcve]

Comment: Just transform response (guess that reactjs has this option) to whatever you want to return. For returnX, you can iterate keys and all keys matching pattern push into result array..

Comment: I am new to react native, Can you post any sample?

Answer (score 1):

Use `startWith` with `getOwnPropertyNames` or `Object.keys( your_object )`.

```js
var apiData = [{
    Value: "895",
    Return: "2",
    Return1: "0.20",
    Return3: "0.40",
    Return5: "0.60",
    Return10: "0.50",
    StartDate: "2019-06-13",
}, {
    Value: "900",
    Return: "4",
    Return1: "0.10",
    Return3: "0.40",
    Return5: "0.70",
    Return10: "0.90",
    StartDate: "2019-06-14",
}]

/* All values of each key thats starts with "Return" in flat array */
const valuesFlat = []
apiData.map( (it, idx) => 
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(it).filter( prop => prop.startsWith("Return") )
 .map( name => apiData[idx][name]  )
 .forEach( its => valuesFlat.push(its) )
)
console.log( "Flat values" )
console.log( valuesFlat )

/* All values of each key thats starts with "Return", not flat array */
const values = apiData.map( (it, idx) => 
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(it).filter( prop => prop.startsWith("Return") )
 .map( name => apiData[idx][name]  )
)
console.log("Values")
console.log(values)


const indexes = apiData.map( (it, idx) => 
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(it)
 .map( (prop, idxs) => { if(prop.startsWith("Return")) return idxs} )
 .filter( prop => prop != undefined )
)
console.log("indexes")
console.log( indexes )



const indexesFlat = []

apiData.forEach( (it, idx) => 
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(it)
 .map( (prop, idxs) => { if(prop.startsWith("Return")) return idxs} )
 .filter( prop => prop != undefined )
 .forEach( it => indexesFlat.push(it) )
)

console.log("Flat indexes")
console.log( indexesFlat )

const flatPropsWithValues = []
apiData.map( (it, idx) => 
 Object.getOwnPropertyNames(it)
 .filter( prop => prop.startsWith("Return") )
 .forEach( prop => flatPropsWithValues.push( { prop: prop, value: apiData[idx][prop] } ) )
)


console.log("Flat props with values")
console.log( flatPropsWithValues )
```

Log.d(TAG, "runON " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex match and a loop instead:

```
const ValueData = [];
const re = new Regex('(Return[0-9]{1,2})');
if (ReturnsData) {
  for (const key in ReturnsData) {
    if (if ReturnsData.hasOwnProperty(key) && re.test(key)) {
      ValueData.push(ReturnsData[key]);
    }
  }
}
```

The regex should match any data starting with 'Return' and ending in one or two numbers. The for...in loop goes through the keys, checks if they exist on the object, and if they match the regex. If they do, the value of that key is added to ValueData.

Answer (score 0):

Returns an array of the values of the keys `Return1`, `Return3`, `Return5`, `Return10`:

```js
const ReturnsData = {
  Value: "900",
  Return: "4",
  Return1: "0.10",
  Return3: "0.40",
  Return5: "0.70",
  Return10: "0.90",
  StartDate: "2019-06-14"
};

const regex = /Return(1|3|5|10)/;

const ValuesData = Object.entries(ReturnsData)
  .filter(([k, v]) => regex.test(k))
  .map(([k, v]) => v);

console.log(ValuesData);
```

Comment: I re-read the question and it looks like you only want `Return1`, `Return3`, `Return5`, `Return10` included so I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Assumptions:**

I am assuming your keys are always like `Return, Return1, Return3, Return5 and Return10` and that your data is already stored in an array (named `ReturnsData`). In that case you could do the following:

```
var ValuesData = []; 
if (ReturnsData) {
  ValuesData = ReturnsData.map((item) => {
      return { item.Return, item.Return1, item.Return3, item.Return5, item.Return10 }; 
  });
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `map` function returns by default a new array. That's why we can store the new array directly in `ValuesData`. Inside the map function, we loop over your objects. Each object's element can then be accessed by `item.YOUR_KEY`. At the end we are returning a new object. Then the next object is being processed.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work :

```
const ValuesData = [];

if (ReturnsData) {
  ReturnsData.map((item, index) => {
    ValuesData.push({
      ReturnsData[index][`Return${index}`],
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: ['Return${index}']}` --> Unexpected template string expression.eslint(no-template-curly-in-string)

Comment: Unexpected string concatenation.eslint(prefer-template)

Comment: I believe there are other better answers, I was just trying to fix the interpolated string for you, this isn't the right solution for what you want.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you would be better to use a forEach rather than map since you aren't aren't assigning that statement to a new array and aren't returning anything within the function body. Within the forEach you can iterate through each key and do a regex test to see if the key starts with "Return." If it does, then push the value associated with that key it into your ValuesData array.

```
let ValuesData = []

ReturnsData.forEach(item => {
    let reg = new RegExp(/^Return.*/)
    for (key in item) {
        if (reg.test(key)) {
            ValuesData.push(item[key]);
        }
    }
})
```

Which gives you the result:

```
["2", "0.20", "0.40", "0.60", "0.50", "4", "0.10", "0.40", "0.70", "0.90"]
```

This will no matter what number comes after Return. So you could have Return12, Return1345, Return76524, etc and still get the desired result.